# Methods of cloud shadow detection for Landsat data?

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, landsat-8, landsat-7

Detecting clouds doesn't seem to be much of a problem, rather the challenge is in selecting cloud-shadow classes that don't also include coastal areas, agriculture, etc.  For a project I'm working on, I've been using two methods:

Fmask (https://code.google.com/p/fmask/) is powerful and fully automated, plus it works for TM, ETM+, and OLI/TIRS data.  It is great at catching harder to detect haze and the majority of other clouds/shadows.  The problem I have with it however is that it tends to miss certain cloud types, namely smaller low altitude clouds and their shadows.  I played around with the input parameters and found the best success using default values.

My other method is a semi-automated classification.  I create NDSI, NDVI, and NDWI for a particular scene, stack those as RGB, and perform unsupervised classification in ERDAS Imagine 2013 (k-means, 10 iterations, 0.95 convergence threshold, and usually 256 classes).  After working on several scenes, I preferred to use the stacked indices over classifying individual bands because it took less time and did a slightly better job at separating clouds/shadows from other classes.

In the end, I had fairly good success with detecting and removing clouds by combining these two methods, but ended up losing good data in my classification of cloud-shadows in particular.  Has anyone had success in removing shadow areas that they'd like to share, or perhaps some insight into improving my classification process?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

1. try using a smaller cloud probability like 12.5 in Fmask
2. try using  the most recent Tmask algorithm that uses the multi-temporal information.